# Ruled section and \dotfill'ed subsection heading

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class and would like to recreate the section and subsection headings from the `moderncv` "banking" style:

[image: moderncvstylefinance]

I was able to create the rule under the section heading using the following:

```
\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
\Large\bfseries\raggedright\strut #1%
\hrule%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}
\setaftersecskip{.5\onelineskip}
```

However, the following subsection style will break the `\dotfill` into a new line:

```
\newcommand{\dottedsubsec}[1]{%
\large\bfseries\raggedright\strut #1%
\scriptsize\dotfill%
}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\dottedsubsec}
\setaftersubsecskip{.25\onelineskip}
```

How can I achieve the desired effect? Is there maybe an easier way to style the headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions.

One approach is to make the afterskip negative, so the dots are run-in to the heading text.  The afterskip dimension then specifies a horizontal skip, which you should set to `0pt`.  The vertical spacing then needs to be added after the `\dotsfill`; unfortunately `\vspace` and `\vspace*` get discarded, so either you need to use `\\[...]`

```
\newcommand{\dottedsubsec}[1]{%
    \large\bfseries\strut #1%
    \dotfill\\[0.25\onelineskip]
    }
```

or, probably better, place the title and dots in a box:

```
\newcommand{\dottedsubsec}[1]{%
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\large\bfseries\strut #1%
\dotfill}\vspace{0.25\onelineskip}%
}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
\Large\bfseries\raggedright\strut #1%
\hrule%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}
\setaftersecskip{.5\onelineskip}

\newcommand{\dottedsubsec}[1]{%
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\large\bfseries\strut #1%
\dotfill}\vspace{0.25\onelineskip}%
}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\dottedsubsec}
\setaftersubsecskip{-0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Experience}
\subsection*{Vocational}
Text.

\end{document}
```

A second approach, which behaves better with respect following lists in your situation, is as follows.  While making the after skip negative solves the run-in problem, it invokes quite a different branch of the `\@startsection` code.  Keeping the after skip positive, one can work around the corresponding coding by killing a `\@@par` command in the `\@startsection` code preventing a line break after the title; the code below does this within in a group to localise the effect:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dottedsubsec}[1]{%
{\noindent\let\@@par\relax\large\bfseries\strut #1%
\dotfill}
}
\makeatother
```

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
\Large\bfseries\raggedright\strut #1%
\hrule%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}
\setaftersecskip{.5\onelineskip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dottedsubsec}[1]{%
{\noindent\let\@@par\relax\large\bfseries\strut #1%
\dotfill}
}
\makeatother
\setsubsecheadstyle{\dottedsubsec}
\setaftersubsecskip{0.25\onelineskip}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

\section*{Experience}
Text.
\subsection*{Vocational}
Text.


\section*{Experience}
\begin{description}
\item[Test] test
\end{description}

\subsection*{Vocational}
\begin{description}
\item[Test] test
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works for adding the dotted line, thanks! However I am getting too much spacing if there's e.g. a list directly below the subsection. Any ideas how I could fix the spacing so that there's no extra line break?

Comment: The updated version is exactly what I was looking for. The look of moderncv is recreated perfectly when using `\scriptsize\dotfill}%` instead of the `\dotfill}` line. Cheers